# HAproxy: redirect from IP to hostname

Tags: proxy, haproxy

I have a proxmox host with multiple VM and multiple webserver, i have a VM with haproxy that redirect external request to internal VM. I need redirect IP request to hostname, if in my browser i type http://public_ip, redirect to http://www.mydomain.com, it's possible with haproxy?

Comment: No, you need to do that in your webserver. Simply define a default virtualhost that does the redirection.

Comment: The public ip is assigned to proxmox host, the port 80/443 is redirect to proxy, not to machine where is apache installed. I must configure haproxy not apache

Comment: If you do an IP request now, does it not end up at a webserver somehow, even if that goes through a proxy? (What proxy, BTW? varnish?). You *can* use `haproxy` to do a redirect (although I prefer to use a webserver to actually respond to the client), you need to setup an `acl` if the `host` header is empty or contains the IP address, and then do a `redirect` to a location if the acl is true (it's all in the `haproxy` documentation). What have you tried already? Add this info to your question.